# JavaScriptInterface not doing anything

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I've been looking into communicating between the main thread and a WebView, but whatever I try, nothing ever seems to happen. And unfortunately I don't really have a Javascript debug console at the ready in Android :-/

It's probably some stupid small mistake again, but I can't find the problem. It simply doesn't do anything. I don't see any errors or whatever.

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById (R.id.web);
    web.getSettings ().setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
    web.setWebChromeClient (new WebChromeClient ());
    JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface (this);
    web.addJavascriptInterface (jsInterface, "accessAndroid");
}

public class JavaScriptInterface
{
    Context context;

    JavaScriptInterface (Context c)
    {
        context = c;
    }

    public void gotoArticle (int id)
    {
        jsHandler.post
        (
            new Runnable ()
            {
                public void run ()
                {
                    //TODO//
                }
            }
        );
    }

    public void showDialog (final String message)
    {
        jsHandler.post
        (
            new Runnable ()
            {
                public void run ()
                {
                    showDialog (message);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

When running `alert ('Something');` from the loaded webpage, all is fine. But `dlg ('Something');` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why the space between `toString` and `()`? Also, have you considered perhaps waiting for the page to be loaded before calling `loadUrl()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare At first I tried applying the settings in the onCreate event, and then running the Javascript stuff when a button was clicked after the page was loaded. Didn't do anything either. The space is just what I'm used to. I like keeping my code readable.